# Laravel issue in sorting grid columns

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm quite new of Laravel, and I'm developing a site in Laravel 5.8 and SqlServer.

At the moment, I'm facing a problem with a sortable column grid.
I have followed the instruction about Kyslink package: https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable.

but for a reason that I don't understand, when I try to open a page with a sortable grid, it appears this message: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortable()"

I found many suggestions about that in internet, but none of these suited me.

Maybe the reason is that my grid reproduce an sql view?

If I remove sortable() method the view works.

//My Controller Method code is like this

```php
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    use Sortable;

    protected $sortable = [
       'id', 'ticket_id', 'type_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'user_id', 'note'
    ];

    public function activities() {

       try {
            $activities = DB::table('activities')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'activities.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->leftJoin('types', 'activities.type_id', '=', 'types.id')
            ->leftJoin('tickets', 'activities.ticket_id', '=', 'tickets.id')
            ->select('activities.*', 'users.name as user_name', 'types.description as type_description', 'tickets.subject')
            ->sortable()
            ->paginate(config('app.num_pages'));
        }
        catch (\Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Exceptions\ColumnSortableException $e) {
            dd($e);
        }

        return view('activity.activities', compact('activities'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Sortable` trait in Model, not Controller!

You should placed `use Sortable;` and

```
protected $sortable = [
    'id', 'ticket_id', 'type_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'user_id', 'note'
];
```

in Model.

Comment: @user1977651 What do you mean "not true"? Have you seen the code here https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable-example/blob/L5.8/app/User.php? Please, check it first, then comment!

Comment: of course I did. but I'm extracting data from a join non a single table with a specific model.

Comment: As you can see in that example it is used sortable in Controller: namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function index(User $user)
    {
        try {
            $users = $user->with('detail')->select(['*', 'name as nick_name'])->sortable()->paginate(10);

            return view('user', ['users' => $users]);
        } catch (\Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Exceptions\ColumnSortableException $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
    }
}

Comment: I don't say "use sortable in Model / Controller". I said, use `Sortable Trait` in Model. In your question, you're using Sortable Trait in Controller, not Model. Please take a look at the link I given to you.

Comment: In UserController, there is no `use Sortable;` and `protected $sortable`. It's should be placed in `User` Model. If you understand my advice, you then should be able to solve your issue. If you don't mind to try my solution, then up to you. Thanks

Comment: What I don't understand is: if my query is a join of multi tables, which is the right model?

Comment: Well I think the issue is on the query!! because if I use just this line code $activities = Activity::sortable()->paginate(5);   it works.

Comment: It's another issue. You should create another question for different issue! Ok, welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that with that package it is not possible sorting join!

> This package doesn't work with joins yet :( and I don't have a lot of
>   time to make it work. Perhaps in winter (northern hemisphere).

here the link: https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable/issues/8#issuecomment-134911114

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

The Controller

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function activities() {
        $activities = Activity::with('user')->with('type')->select(['*'])->sortable()->paginate(config('app.num_pages'));
    return view('activity.activities', compact('activities'));
    }   
}
```

This is the Model:

`namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;

class Activity extends Model
{
    use Sortable;

    protected $table = 'activities';

    protected $fillable = [
        'ticket_id', 'type_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'user_id', 'note'
    ];

    protected $sortable = [
       'id', 'ticket_id', 'type_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'user_id', 'note'
   ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Type::class, 'id', 'type_id');
    }`